# Arduino C: undefined reference to `readArms()'

Tags: c, function, arduino

While compiling some Arduino C file I get an error "undefined reference to `readArms()'"

The code can be found on [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/NQD5mLGE).

But basically what happens is:

In the INO file I use:

```
readArms();
```

Which is declared in "armfunctions.h" and "armfunctions.c"

The .h file contains

```
void readArms(void);
```

And the .c file :

```
void readArms(void){
    float motor1 = 0.0;
    int motor = 0;
    motor = analogRead(READMOTOR1);
    motor1 = (float)motor;
    motor1 = (motor1 - 87.0) * (400.0/(1007.0-87.0));
    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Did you pass `"armfunctions.c"` to the compiler ?

Comment: Yes, all of these files age in the same folder, and all of them appear in the arduino SDK when I open the .INO file

Comment: Changing armfunctions.c to armfunctions.cpp solved the problem

Comment: Then put this comment into an answer such that others can see it clearly and benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 28):

I have been researching this for hours today, making and testing various sketches, and have found (as you've already found) changing them to `.cpp` is a workaround, but if you want to specifically create a c file, you must wrap the prototypes in the header to get it to compile. There are a few good posts about it, but the crux of the issue, in your `.h` file put:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void readArms(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use the following in your .C file:

```
void armfunctions::readArms(void)... 
// (the part in front of the :: is your classname in your .h file)
```

Comment: `c` is a C source code file extension, not a C++ one. Namespaces and classes do not exist in C. Writing C++ code in a C file is not a valid solution.